# How to add an "entity" field using doctrine:generate:entity?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

The question is really simple but I didn't find any answer on the big Internet.

How can I add a entity field while generating a new entity using doctrine:generate:entity ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set up relationships manually there is no way around it short of extending the generator bundle yourself.